# Calling setTimeout from child process (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to call a function through setTimeout using a child process, which may exit before the setTimeout occurs.

1) I assume that if the child process calls the function (even if it's defined externally), the setTimeout will be cancelled if the child process exits. Is this correct?

2) If so, would it be feasible to have the child process signal the parent process to execute the setTimeout instead, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but let me provide some potentially applicable links and examples.

Sending and receiving messages between the master and child process are possible with [child.send / process.send](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) which is part of the child_process module and cluster.

For example, clearing a setTimeout when the child process sends a message to the master:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/sub.js');

var timer = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('timed out'); 
}, 5000);

child.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

The child

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('finished doing some long task');
  process.send({ status: 'done' });
}, 3000); // set this to something larger than 5000ms to see the timeout
```

You might also be interested in the [exit](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) and [close](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close) event for a child process to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for taking a swing at this. What I'm primarily interested in is the behaviour of a setTimeout called by a process after the process has ended. I assume it does not run, so I am trying to find a way to have a child process call a setTimeout which executes regardless of whether or not the child process exists when the setTimeout needs to run.

Comment: Hmm.. the example provided shows how you can run a setTimeout regardless of the existence of a child, but in regards to making a setTimeout started from within a child remain after the child exits, I don't believe it is possible as the process running the timer is no longer running. The only way is in some process, parent or other child, that remains.

Comment: That's what I thought. So, now what I'm wondering is whether I can achieve this by sending a message to the parent, who in turn executes the setTimeout. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: I have outlined that approach, I'm not aware of a better approach but that doesn't mean anything.